# Select video url according to internet quality

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview, exoplayer

I have a list of .mp4 video urls with different quality[1080p, 720p, 360p]. I would like to play the video on my app using Exo player, but set the URL according to the users network quality. How can i implement this ?

My specific problem is finding the users network quality.

Answer (score 0):

You can track the speed of the network using the ConnectivityManager

```
ConnectivityManager manager=(ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkCapabilities nc = manager.getNetworkCapabilities(manager.getActiveNetwork());
int downloadSpeed = nc.getLinkDownstreamBandwidthKbps();
int uploadSpeed = nc.getLinkUpstreamBandwidthKbps();
```

and based on speed you can categories which image you want to pick. Following description will help you to decide whether network speed is high, moderate or low

```
POOR // Network Speed less than 150 kbps.
MODERATE // Network Speed between 150 and 550 kbps.
GOOD // Network Speed upto 2000 kbps.
EXCELLENT // Network Speed over 2000 kbps.
UNKNOWN // connection quality cannot be found.
```

Comment: Refer the Google documentation for more details https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html